# What's the difference between annehmen and akzeptieren?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, swiss-german

This is the example:

> They will not accept your registration.

I have used *akzeptieren*.

> Sie werden deine Anmeldung nicht akzeptieren.

Translator shows:

> Nehmen sie Ihre Anmeldung nicht an.

As a native speaker what would you prefer as the right word in this registration context?

Comment: "Annehmen" sounds more polite here, in my opinion.

Comment: Welcher Translator? "Sie nehmen Ihre Anm. nicht an" wäre eine Option, "Nehmen sie ..." dagegen nicht, Satzbaufehler.

Comment: Note that "will" can be ambiguous; it can mean future tense but there are several other meanings. I think in this context the meaning may be closer to "used to express intention but without any temporal connotations" (per Wiktionary). So perhaps translating with "wollen" would be more accurate. So for "Will you marry me?" use "Willst du mich heiraten?" rather than "Wirst du mich heiraten?". To me, more context is needed to say whether "werden" or "wollen" is a better fit in "will not accept".

Comment: @RDBury future tense..
Considering context is "tomorrow". If you reach tomorrow late, they will not accept your registration.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is fine, that one of the translator you use is completely off.

About the question, both *akzeptieren* and *annehmen* are synonymous in this context. But *nicht akzeptieren* is very formal speech and if used in an otherwise informal context, it means stern opposition.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation is correct, the translator is plain wrong.

Both "annehmen" and "akzeptieren" mean the same thing here.

Please note that in common usage, "nicht akzeptieren" means I cannot accept it because it is too low/little/late, while "nicht annehmen" might also mean that it is too much to accept (for example concerning a gift).